# Using class as type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why can I use class as type in TypeScript, like `word: Word` in the code below?

```js
class Dict {
  private words: Words = {};
// I wonder about this line
  add(word: Word) {
    if (!this.words[word.term]) {
      this.words[word.term] = word.def;
    }
  }
}

class Word {
  constructor(term: string, def: string) {}
}
```

I wanted to understand it through official document but couldn't find related content.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html. But really: why not?

Comment: If this question was really answered by someone else googling "typescript class" for you, then I'd urge you to do a little more research before asking. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see anything in that document that directly addresses the idea of using class names as types. Did I miss something?

Comment: Answering the question "why not?": tokens in TypeScript generally either represent JavaScript code or represent typing which is provided _on top of_ that code. Usually this is a clear division in TS syntax. E.g., error #2749 specifically warns the user they've used a token representing a value in a place where a type was expected (`'x' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here`). Or e.g., the `typeof` type operator converts a value into its type.

Comment: By serving both purposes, class names are quite the exception to the rule. This is especially relevant in a language that [describes itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) as offering "an additional layer on top of [JavaScript]", by which it means its type system.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I just googled "typescript class" and the first few links I tried don't answer this question. Like the documentation Jon linked to, most are concerned with explaining class declarations as a language feature in general, and don't directly address their additional role as type declarations. Note that this functionality doesn't simply follow from a combination of JS classes and TS type inference, but instead requires TS treat classes differently on a _syntactic_ level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in most statically typed languages. By annotating word with `Word` you can access its class properties.

More info:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-class